# Magento 2.3 - Getting website id in the Observer

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3.4

My observer :

```
<?php
namespace Gta\EnablePaymentMethod\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class PaymentMethodEnable implements ObserverInterface {
  
    protected $_customerSession;
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
       $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }


    protected $_storeManager;
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }



    public function execute(Observer $observer) {

      $website_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
      if($website_id == '1')
      {

      $payment_method_code = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
      if ($payment_method_code == 'paypal_express') {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $result->setData('is_available', false);
       if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
           $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
           if ($customerGroupId == 9) {
               $result->setData('is_available', true);
            }
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

Getting Fatal error:

**Fatal error**:  Cannot redeclare Gta\EnablePaymentMethod\Observer\PaymentMethodEnable::__construct() in **/var/www/html/test/app/code/Gta/EnablePaymentMethod/Observer/PaymentMethodEnable.php** on line **15**

How to solve the error?

Note : Without website id condition observer working, i want to add website Id.

Comment: you have redeclare constuct function so

Comment: Any help to correct my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with my code

```
<?php
namespace Gta\EnablePaymentMethod\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class PaymentMethodEnable implements ObserverInterface {
  
    protected $_customerSession;

    protected $_storeManager;



    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
       $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }




    public function execute(Observer $observer) {

      $website_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
      if($website_id == '1')
      {

      $payment_method_code = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
      if ($payment_method_code == 'paypal_express') {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $result->setData('is_available', false);
       if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
           $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
           if ($customerGroupId == 9) {
               $result->setData('is_available', true);
            }
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

and run again `compile` command

Comment: After enable and disable the module, what is the command to run, shall i run all the commands like an upgrade, compiled, static content deploy?

Comment: Here how can i add Guest Customer condition, the guest customer also not eligible to pay PayPal.

Comment: @zus can you post another question here is write about website id related code

Comment: We put condition only for a customer group 9, so that guest customer also not able to pay via PayPal. Thank You

Comment: Any help on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/339482/57334 thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
<?php
namespace Gta\EnablePaymentMethod\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class PaymentMethodEnable implements ObserverInterface {
  
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }



    public function execute(Observer $observer) {

      $website_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
      if($website_id == '1')
      {

      $payment_method_code = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
      if ($payment_method_code == 'paypal_express') {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $result->setData('is_available', false);
       if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
           $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
           if ($customerGroupId == 9) {
               $result->setData('is_available', true);
            }
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error, 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Gta\EnablePaymentMethod\Observer\PaymentMethodEnable

Comment: Share full error log please

Comment: Compile command solve the issue

Comment: ok @zus 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You've two `__construct` with same name. I don't know why would you need that, you can simple put both dependency injections in one constructor like shown below:

```
public function __construct(
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
```