# Magento 2 - How to update Google Business Reviews Authorization Bearer Token?

Tags: magento2.4.1, google-api, token

I am using Google Business Review API, every time i manually copy and paste the token key,

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: from where you are generating(copy) token and where pasting.

Comment: 0Auth OAuth 2.0 Playground,

Comment: Step 1 : Select & authorize APIs => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage & Step 1's resultAccess token retrieved => Access token generated & Step 2 : Configure request to API => After enter Request URI  & Request / Response return the token then i paste into magento

Comment: Finally, i want to show my google business review on my page. Reviews displayed but every time i manually run 0Auth https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground then i copy token then paste into magento, how to achieve this? Any best way pls suggest.

Comment: are you using any "Authorization Code" for retrieve token ?

Comment: Using OAuth Client ID

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/  => Credientials section Here i can get Client ID

Comment: @Pawan Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes I tried to create token using lib https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client and first it ask me to login and after login, it provide code me for generate token BUT I am getting `invalid_client` error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126446/discussion-between-pawan-and-zus).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126452/discussion-between-zus-and-pawan).

Comment: please use this link : https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/implement-oauth I hope you can got the solution